# Revealing Module Pattern return value convention

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, convention, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

If I have a module with lots of stuff like this:

```
My.Module = (function () {
    function method1 () {}
    function method2 () {}
    ...
    function method99 () {}

    return {
        method1: method1,
        method2: method2,
        ...
        method99: method99
    };
})();
```

How could I avoid repeating the method names? They all appear in three places.

If I were to use a local variable like this:

```
My.Module = (function () {
    var exp = {};

    exp.method1 = function () {};
    exp.method2 = function () {};
    ...
    exp.method99 = function () {};

    return exp;
})();
```

What should the `exp` variable be called? `exp`, `exports`, `exported`, `obj`, `object`? Does it matter? What's the convention?

If there's a way that is better than both of these, what is it?

Comment: the name does not matter, it is just the reference to the object returning.

Comment: @NinaScholz I understand that the name doesn't affect the code in any way, but is there a convention for it? Is there a widely accepted name I can use which would immediately tell the reader "oh yeah, that's the public stuff"?

Comment: just call it what it keeps.

Comment: how are the methods generated? does the name reflects some content?

Comment: Nope. I ended up calling it `reveal` like `reveal.someMethod = ...` and then `return reveal`. Since it's _revealing_ module pattern, I guess that's a pretty suitable name.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is the cleanest way IMO.

As for the var name in your secnd method, name, it whatever you like the name won't be exposed. `Module` should be good.

But, if you really do not want to repeat the function names, you can do :

```
My.Module = (function () {

    return {
        method1: function method1 () {},
        ...
        method99: function method99 () {}
    };
})();
```